# vba dictionary when I transpose the dictionary Items, I get all zeros

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, key-value

The first thing I do is create a scripting dictionary setting the Keys from each row in a column and the number zero as the item. In subsequent code, when conditions are met, I pull a Key's Item as an integer, add 1 to it and replace the 0 with a 1 in the dictionary.

For testing the code, when I call the Key specifically I get a 1 for the Item as intended. When I transpose the Items of that dictionary into a column, it gives me all zeros. When I set it up as iterating through a For Loop, placing the Items into subsequent rows within a column, I still get all zeros.

I'm not worried about maximums, there are only like 40 recruiters I'm checking.

Edited:
I slept on it and thought I would put in some more testing code. I did a dictionary count right after the dictionary is created and it came up 41. After the code goes through I placed another count and found out it comes up to 42.

What allows you to have two keys in a dictionary that are the same?

Ideas?

LRR and LR?? is a last row variable for reference

```
'This creates the dictionary. Recruiter Key with a 0 item
Set RecGoalCount = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each RecDesk In Sheets("Recruiters").Range("B2:B" & LRR)

        RecGoalCount.Add RecDesk, 0

    Next RecDesk
```

```
''''Here is the code that will change the dictionary item to a 1. The way _
''''it processes the sheet right now, there is only one instance where all _
''''are true which is why only 1 item gets changed from a 0 to a 1.
RecMatch = 0
For Each job In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & LRS2)

    For Each job2 In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:X" & LRS1)

        OneOfInQW = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:X" & LRS1), job)
        CurrentCol = job2.Column
        TrgtCol = CurrentCol - 4
        TrgtCell = job2.Offset(0, -TrgtCol).Value2
        RefCell = job.Offset(0, 1).Value2

            If job = job2 And OneOfInQW = 1 And RefCell >= TrgtCell Then

                    LRS3 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                    TrgtRec = CurrentCol - 1
                    TrgtCol = CurrentCol - 2
                    TrgtCell = job2.Offset(0, -TrgtCol).Value2
                    TrgtKey = job2.Offset(0, -TrgtRec).Value2

                    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & (LRS3 + 1)).Value = TrgtCell

                    RecMatch = Int(RecGoalCount(TrgtKey))
                    RecMatch = RecMatch + 1
                    RecGoalCount.Item(TrgtKey) = Str(RecMatch)

                    job2.EntireRow.ClearContents

                    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & (LRS3 + 1)).Value = job
                    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & (LRS3 + 1)).Value = job.Offset(0, 1)

                    job.Clear

                    job.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & (LRS3 + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

            Exit For
            End If

    Next job2

Next job
```

```
Sheets("Recruiters").Range("E2:E" & LRR) = Application.Transpose(RecGoalCount.Items)
      'This is where I get all 0s despite a condition in the code changing exactly 1 Item to a 1
Sheets("Recruiters").Range("F2:F" & LRR) = Application.Transpose(RecGoalCount.Keys)
      'This is just proving to me that it captured the correct keys with the correct names, check.
Sheets("Recruiters").Range("H2") = RecGoalCount("14CBBPG")
      'This proves to me that the Item became a 1
Recs = RecGoalCount.Count
      'This proves to me that after the code that changes the item, the total _
       count of the dictionary didn't change either.
```

```
'This code iterates through the dictionary keys to give the items, and it _
    gives me all 0s despite one of the items being turned into a 1
x = 2
    For Each Rec In RecGoalCount

        Sheets("Recruiters").Range("E" & x) = RecGoalCount(Rec)
        x = x + 1

    Next Rec
```

Comment: show the code that changes dictionary items into 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I was able to identify that I was adding a new key instead of updating one I just had to google how a dictionary could have duplicate looking keys. It was in how I was creating the dictionary. I was adding the key as a cell and not as a value.

Thanks for your considerations.